# Android Anonymous Delegate

Tags: android

Coming from a .NET C# background, new to Java....

How do I re-write this code to point the listener to a normal function?

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
    //Some Code Here;
     }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "normal function"? Do you mean a concrete class that
implements the View.OnClickListener interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java follows a different concept than C#, it uses 'Anonymous Classes' for this approach.
Maybe you should check out Java docs for it.

It is like implement a interface on the fly by a anonymous class.